# AngularJS Позиционированный вывод фото

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

Передав в функцию load идентификатор, достаю из таблицы имена файлов из которых в дальнейшем генерирую ссылки и по клику вывожу ссылки на фото.

```
<div ng-repeat="img in photo">
<a href=""  ng-click="showImg = !showImg;load(img.id)">Show images</a>
<span id="list_photo" ng-show="showImg"></span>
</div>
```

Функция:

```
$scope.image = function (id) {
$http.get('http://site.com/photo/img/'+id)
 .then(function success(response) {
  img = response.data;
  console.log('Ответ: ', response.data);
   var currentIndex = 0;
   $("#list_photo").html("<img src='#' />");
   $("#list_photo > img").click(function () {
    if (currentIndex >= img.length)
     currentIndex = 0;
     $(this).attr("src", "/public/upload/pict/"+ img[currentIndex++].filename);
   });
   $("#list_photo > img").click();
  });
};
```

Дело в том, что открывается почему-то только фотография, ссылка которой находится выше всех, т.е. последняя. Если клацаю на остальные `Show images`, в консоли вижу, что имена файлов возвращаются, но возле ссылки фотка не открывается. Как можно привязать эти фото к конкретным позициям `Show images`?

Comment: Вам уже в каком-то вопросе указывали. Не используйте `$.ajax` в ангуляр приложении. У ангуляра есть свой `$http`.

Comment: Ajax я перепишу в $http. Тут проблемы нет. Понять бы как связать каждую ссылку со своим фото

Comment: Вы сначала перепишите в `$http`. Затем перестаньте создавать элементы с помощью `jQuery`. А потом и проблема сама пропадет)

Comment: Переписал функцию под $http.get. Но чем заменить тут кусок начинающийся с var currentIndex = 0, затрудняюсь ответить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо думать, как решать задачу не через `jQuery`, а через `angular`. У него свои подходы.

Я бы вам советовал убрать из вашего проекта `jQuery` **вообще**. Это поможет думать, не опираясь на опыт с `jQuery`.

Важные отличия:

- в `jQuery` мы часто создаем элементы, привязываем к ним события.
- в `angular` мы пользуемся уже готовым шаблоном, с готовыми событиями.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6Lbwgf9m/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function(PhotoService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showImg = false;
    vm.photos = [{
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2
    }];
    vm.load = function(photo) {
      vm.showImg = !vm.showImg;
      //Не загружать повторно, если уже загрузили
      if (photo.images)
        return;
      PhotoService.getPhoto(photo.id)
        .then(function success(response) {
          photo.images = response.data;
          console.log('Ответ: ', response.data);
        });
    };
  })
  .service("PhotoService", function($http, $q) {
    this.getPhoto = function(id) {
      //симуляция запроса
      return $q.resolve({
        data: [{
          filename: "https://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" + id,
        }, {
          filename: "https://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" + (id * 2),
        }, {
          filename: "https://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" + (id * 3),
        }]
      });
      //В реальности делаем запрос к серверу
      //return $http.get('http://site.com/photo/img/' + id);      
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="photo in vm.photos">
      <a href="" ng-click="vm.load(photo)">Show images</a>
      <span ng-show="vm.showImg">
        <!-- Вместо динамического построений элементов, мы отрисовываем уже существующие. -->
        <img ng-repeat="img in photo.images" ng-src="{{img.filename}}" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: В вашем варианте выгружаются все фото. А реально ли отображать фото по одному, а при клике по нему отображать поочерёдно остальные?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов Пожалуйста, обновите ваш вопрос с описанием желаемого поведения. Описание желательно дать максимально подробно. Лучше показать *HTML* код который должен получиться.

Comment: Только что разобрался. Вопрос уже в другом! Не могу сформировать корректно ссылку. Исходя из того, что я в проекте использую Twig, для работы Angular использую метод замены {{}} на // //. Так вот при генерации ссылки, выходит нечто подобное: site.ru/photo/pict//img.filename// - что конечно работать никак не может. Смешно и грешно, но нет мыслей как это обойти?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов извините, без кода я помочь не смогу. Сложно сказать, что не работает, когда не видишь, как это сделано.

Comment: В любом случае, всего Вам доброго за помощь!