# AngularJS Перезаписывающие значения

Tags: angularjs

Переходя по ссылкам, вывожу имена файлов по идентификатору. Проблема в том, что полученные функцией имена, при каждом клике на ссылке переписывают ранее выведенные.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in items">
<a href="" ng-click="showImg = !showImg;file(event.rid);" ng-show="!showImg">Show filename</a>
<a href="" ng-click="showImg = !showImg;" ng-show="showImg">Hide filename</a>
<div ng-repeat="fl in files">
<p ng-show="showImg">// fl.filename //</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Функция:

```
$scope.file = function (rid) {
                $http.get('http://site.com/file/filename/'+rid)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        $scope.files = response.data;
                    }, function error(err) {
                        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
                });
            };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не внимательно скопировали код из предыдущего ответа. Посмотрите внимательно, чем они отличаются? Подсказка - смотреть в строке `$scope.files = response.data`

Comment: если вы про: ng-repeat="fl in file(event.rid)", то в таком случае происходит уход в бесконечный цикл и баста. Или я путаю?

Comment: Нет ,я не про это. Я про место сохранения вашего ответа от сервера. Посмотрите строчку `$scope.files = response.data;` и `photo.images = response.data;` из ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729036/angularjs-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: Суть вроде понял. Спасибо